# Evaluate $1-\frac{1}{3\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 3^2}-\frac{1}{7\cdot 3^3}+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**My attempt**
$$1-\frac{1}{3\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 3^2}-\frac{1}{7\cdot 3^3}+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)3^{n-1}}$$

By Leibniz alternative test for convergence. It is a convergent alternative series. How do I evaluate this limit?

Answer (score 5):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)3^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)3^{n}}=\sqrt{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}(1/\sqrt{3})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}
$$
$$
=\sqrt{3}\arctan(1/\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{6}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over \pars{2n - 1}3^{n - 1}} = &
-3\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1/3}^{n} \over 2n - 1} =
-\,\root{3}\ic\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic/\root{3}}^{2n -1} \over 2n - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
-\root{3}\ic\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic/\root{3}}^{n} \over n}\,{1^{n} - \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
\root{3}\,\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic/\root{3}}^{n} \over n}
\\[5mm] & =
-\root{3}\Im\ln\pars{1 - {\root{3} \over 3}\,\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
-\root{3}\arctan\pars{-\,{\root{3} \over 3}} 
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi}
\end{align}